# Load From array matrix to array of array Matrix issue

Tags: c, arrays, matrix

I'm in C and I have a file that contains an array matrix (matrix saved as single array). But I need to load this as an array of array matrix

Here the original array matrix load

```
float* loadm(char* filename, int *m, int *n) {  
    FILE* fp;
    int rows, cols, status;

    fp = fopen(filename, "rb");
    status = fread(&cols, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
    status = fread(&rows, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
    float* Xy = alloc_ma(rows,cols);
    status = fread(Xy, sizeof(float), rows*cols, fp);
    fclose(fp);


    return Xy;
}
```

Here my attempt to load the array matrix returning its array of array equivalent

```
float** loadm(char* filename, int *m, int *n) {
    FILE* fp;
    int rows, cols, status;

    fp = fopen(filename, "rb");
    status = fread(&cols, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
    status = fread(&rows, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
    float* Xy = alloc_ma(rows,cols);

    status = fread(Xy, sizeof(float), rows*cols, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    int i=0,j=0;
    float** res=alloc_maa(m, n);
    for(i=0; i<m; i++) {
        for(j=0; j<n; j--) {
            res[i][j]=Xy[i*(n+1)+j];
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```

Unfortunately doesn't work and get this error

```
error: invalid operands to binary * (have ‘int’ and ‘int *’)
```

at the line

```
res[i][j]=Xy[i*(n+1)+j];
```

the allocation methods for array matrix

```
void* get_block(int size, int elements) {
    return _mm_malloc(elements*size,16);
}

float* alloc_matrix(int rows, int cols) {
    return (float*) get_block(sizeof(float),rows*cols);
}
```

the allocation method for array of array matrix

```
float **allocate_maa(int m, int n) {
    int i;
    float **matx = malloc(m*sizeof(*matx));
    for(i=0; i<m; i++) {
        matx[i]=malloc(n*sizeof(**matx));
    }
    return matx;
}
```

EDIT

I have tried this code, to load the matrix saved as array and retur this as a matryx in array of array form

```
float** loadm(char* filename, int *rows, int *cols) {
    FILE* fp;
    int status;

    fp = fopen(filename, "rb");
    status = fread(cols, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
    status = fread(rows, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
    float* Xy = alloc_ma(*rows,*cols);

    status = fread(Xy, sizeof(float), (*rows)*(*cols), fp);
    fclose(fp);

    int row=0,col=0;
    float** res=alloc_maa(*rows, *cols);
    for(row=0; row < (*rows); row++) {
        for(col=0; col < (*cols); col--) {
            res[i][j]=Xy[(row * (*cols)) + col];
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```

but get a segmentation fault error at line

```
res[i][j]=Xy[(row * ((*cols)+1)) + col];
```

Comment: `for(i=0; i<m; i++) { for(j=0; j<n; j--) {
 res[i][j]=Xy[i*(n+1)+j];
 }
}` : but `int *m, int *n`.,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are mixing variables that are accessed by [dereferencing the pointer](http://denniskubes.com/2012/08/16/the-5-minute-guide-to-c-pointers/)(m, n) and
variables that are accessed by value(rows, cols).

May be your function should actually look like:

```
float** loadm(char* filename, int *rows, int *cols) {
    FILE* fp;
    int status;

    fp = fopen(filename, "rb");
    status = fread(cols, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
    status = fread(rows, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
    float* Xy = alloc_ma(*rows,*cols);

    status = fread(Xy, sizeof(float), (*rows)*(*cols), fp);
    fclose(fp);

    int row=0,col=0;
    float** res=alloc_maa(*rows, *cols);
    for(row=0; row < (*rows); row++) {
        for(col=0; col < (*cols); col--) {
            res[i][j]=Xy[(row * ((*cols)+1)) + col];
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```

Why do you need rows and cols variables in the function when you definitely want to return them to the caller - he should know the size of the returned matrix in the end.

Or, using the original code, you could:

```
...
float** res=alloc_maa(rows, cols);
    for(i=0; i<rows; i++) {
        for(j=0; j<cols; j--) {
            res[i][j] = Xy[i*(rows+1)+j];
        }
    }

*m = cols;
*n = rows;
return res;
...
```

to avoid multiple dereferencing.

Also:

```
res[i][j] = Xy[(i * ((*cols) + 1)) + j];
```

If your matrix is 5 x 5 then the item[1, 0] has the corresponding item in the Xy array with index 5(as it has 5 items before it with indexes from 0 to 4), while the code snippet above will give you index `(i * ((*cols) + 1)) + j` = 6. May be something is wrong here?

Comment: in this way compiles but I get segmentation fault error

Comment: Have you removed the '+1' in your indexing?

Comment: Sorry, i was mistaken with alloc_maa.

Comment: At which line do you get the segmentation error? Step through the debugger.

Comment: at `res[i][j] = Xy[(i * ((*cols) + 1)) + j];`  if I change in  `res[i][j]=Xy[(i * (*cols)) + j];` get the same crash

Comment: What are the values of i, j, *cols?

Comment: Try also to use 'float temp = Xy[(i * (*cols)) + j]; res[i][j] = temp;'. In that way we will know which array causes the problem.

Comment: m is 1024 n is 512, the i and j are 0 when crashes because crash at first iteration... the original metod for matrix as array works fine, the issue is in the editing to returns an array of array matrix

Comment: Are you sure that your mallocs succeeded - you never check for failure.

Comment: Edit your post to include the code you are currently using.

Comment: I haved used alloc_maa to allocate successfully other matrix (although not in this kind of operation). 

I have copy-pasted the method that currently I'm trying

Comment: Your indexing code is still incorrect: Xy[(row * ((*cols)+1)) + col] does not need +1

Comment: Look in debugger for values of res, res[0].

Comment: I have found the error, look at j--, should be j++. anyway thanks for the help

Comment: I was blind. Well, that's another proof that the error is usually where you do not expect it to find.

Answer (score 0):

In the `res[i][j]=Xy[i*(n+1)+j];` code line n is a pointer to an integer. You need to deference it, to get the n value you want. `res[i][j]=Xy[i*(*n+1)+j];` will fix your compiler error.

Comment: in this way compiles but I get segmentation fault error